# Altering the Documents Directory Changes the Folder Name

Tags: windows, windows-10, rename, documents

I set up my Documents folder location to use the D drive on my computer and now it is stuck with the folder name D:/ - however when I go into properties it says that it is Documents. How can I get it to change the folder name back to Documents?

Edit:
Steps I took were...

1. RMB Documents (in sidebar under Quick Access)
2. Location - Move/Change to D:/
3. Save

Now by default any documents saved to the Documents folder will be saved to the drive D:/ (Documents) rather than in the C:/Users/

Here's a screenshot (on Windows 10).
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: "I set up my Documents folder location to use the D drive" - what **exactly** did you do? Please [edit] your question to tell us (step by step).

Answer (score 0):

RMB to "documents" (D:/), go to **properties**, **location** tab. It should show the absolute path where documents are stored & allow you to change it or restore it to default.

Comment: Thank you, but I am aware how to restore it to default. I would like to keep it located in the D:/ location but have it read Documents while looking in My PC rather than the drive path.

Comment: What exactly the path displayed in **location** tab show for you?